# can we animate the view while updating padding in openlayers 6.5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6

I am trying to update padding or View while the side menu is open or close on my website. but when I update the padding map also updates its position. I want to animate the map view while updating the padding of the view.

i am using following code to update padding:

`view.padding = [50, 50, 50, 150]`

or

`view.padding = [50, 50, 50, 50]`

Comment: That was a bug https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/11938#issuecomment-766177808  It should be fixed in the dev version.

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue with the current release(6.5.0) and it will be fixed in the next version.